# Time difference convert to integer does not work

Tags: php, timestamp

I found the time difference using **strtotime()**,it works.
But when I check a condition using **if(){}** condition makes always false(even,when I tried to condition make true).
Code is below.please help to find a solution.

```
$diff = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime('2019-01-01');

$new_diff = (int)$diff; 
$max = (int)60;

if($new_diff > $max){           
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("location:index.php");
}else{
    header("location:add.php");
}
```

(time difference shows in 'Seconds')

But , my expected result is redirecting to the  **if(){}**.

Comment: I checked your code and it is giving 'A' in output, So, I belive everything is working fine. Check this https://3v4l.org/2V5AK

Comment: https://3v4l.org/XtI53

Comment: Hi @AnkurTiwari I changed the bug to my real situation. can you please check again..?

Comment: Your updated code doesn't change the fact that running the code you've provided runs what is in the `if` not the `else`. Are you saying you _want_ it to be running the `else`?

Comment: No I need to go to inside the **if(){}**

Comment: @Thisaru Well that's what it does. Is your date / time set correctly on the machine you're running this on? Add `var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Yes @JonStirling those are ok..

Comment: Then I see no reason (or evidence) that would support you saying it's entering the else.

Comment: @Thisaru try to echo $new_diff and $max share your output here.

Comment: @Thisaru Also you are getting any of the above dates dynamically?

Comment: @AnkurTiwari yes. I apply date from database

Comment: Can you show the values here?